# Asserting several fields, with different priorities, in the same test with Pytest

Tags: python, pytest

I'm using pytest to test the output of a function for different test data (too cumbersome to transform them into individual tests).
I'm using fixture `@pytest.mark.parametrize` for that.

In our test, we're asserting the equality between `expected_result[field_i]` and `obtained_result[field_i]` from different fields.

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("files,expected_data", test_data)
def test_func_name(files,expected_data):
    assert expected_result[field_1] == expected_result[field_1]
    assert expected_result[field_2] == expected_result[field_2]
    assert expected_result[field_3] == expected_result[field_3]
```

However, not all fields have the same importance. My highest priority is the field_1 (related to dates), and the remaining ones could be wrong, but it would be better if they were right.

Right now, if one of the fields is wrong, we have that test failing.
Is there a way to prevent this behaviour, and make the test fail or pass score based solely on dates, but also give a some extra 'positive marks' to those which also pass the remaining fields?

Comment: What do you mean by extra "positive marks"? A test either fails or it passes; there's not a scoring system. If you only really care about `field_1`, then just test `field_1`. You could mark tests for the remaining fields as [`xfail`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/skipping.html), so if they fail they won't cause pytest to report a failure.

Comment: I would assert for the field you care about and for the 'nice to haves' use something like `pytest.warns`

Comment: @larsks would you recommend creating new tests for the different fields?

Comment: Maybe two tests, one for the required field, one for all the others so that you can mark it appropriately?

Comment: @TeejayBruno I don't think `pytest.warns` is going to help, that's for [capturing warning messages](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/warnings.html#warns). Maybe you were thinking of something else?

Comment: @larsks you're right -- I thought the pytest version could both capture and output, but it's capture only. In that case I would use `warnings.warn`, thought process is to alert the user the 'nice to haves ' failed without affecting the test run.